# SWT GC clipping circle

Tags: java, swt

I'd like to use GC to clip the area outside the circle.

GC has `setClipping (Rectangle rect)`, but doesn't have setClipping for circle.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the other method:

```
public void setClipping(Region region)
```

Here an example, you have to create a Region like this:

```
Region region = new Region();
int r = 10;
int x = 100;
int y = 100;
// int d = (2 * r); // diameter
region.add(circle(r, (x + r), (y + r)));
```

where circle is the following method:

```
public static int[] circle(int r, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
    int[] polygon = new int[8 * r + 4];
    // x^2 + y^2 = r^2
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * r + 1; i++) {
        int x = i - r;
        int y = (int) Math.sqrt(r * r - x * x);
        polygon[2 * i] = offsetX + x;
        polygon[2 * i + 1] = offsetY + y;
        polygon[8 * r - 2 * i - 2] = offsetX + x;
        polygon[8 * r - 2 * i - 1] = offsetY - y;
    }
    return polygon;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `GC.setClipping(Path path)`.

To create a path representing a circle, create an empty `Path` and then add a circle to it with `addArc`:

```
Path circlePath = new Path(gc.getDevice());
circlePath.addArc(x, y, width, height, 0.f, 360.f);
gc.setClipping(circlePath);
```